# Alter Size Salient Divine Ability referring to Improving Monsters Size Increases?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, creature-size, divine

The Alter Size Salient Divine Ability states

> As a free action, the deity can assume any size from Fine to Colossal. The deity also can change the size of up to 100 pounds of objects it touches. If the deity has a familiar, personal mount, or personal intelligent weapon, the creature can change size with the deity if the deity touches it, but its weight counts against the deity’s weight limit. This is a supernatural ability.

> Notes
> This ability allows the deity to assume any proportions from the size of a grain of sand up or as much as 1,600 feet tall. A radical change in size can have great impact on the deity’s combat ability. The deity’s Strength, Armor Class, attack bonus, and damage dealt with weapons changes according to the size the deity assumes. The deity’s Strength score can never be reduced to less than 1 through this ability. Also note that use of this divine ability does not affect all the deities’ characteristics.

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#alterSize

Do the adjustments mentioned refer to the size adjustments for improving monsters table?

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#sizeIncreases

The text of Alter Size states '*The deity’s Strength, Armor Class, attack bonus, and damage dealt with weapons changes according to the size the deity assumes.*' and '*Also note that use of this divine ability does not affect all the deities’ characteristics.*'

So referring to the size increase table is it correct to assume the only adjustments made when considering that table are taken from the Strength column and AC / Attack column AND NOT any adjustment from the Dex, Con, Natural Armor columns?

The reason I ask is I'm currently in the process of 3.5-ising Nyarlathotep from CoC D20 and need to get it correct as an epic threat for my players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The size increase from *Alter Size* only affects Strength, AC, Attack Bonus and Weapon Damage.

*Salient Divine Abilities* originally appeared in *Deities and Demigods*. Different from the SRD, the book version also provides tables (p 34 and 35)  that show the exact changes that occur.

> The deity’s Strength, Armor Class, attack bonus, and damage dealt with
> weapons changes according to the size the deity assumes, **as shown on
> the accompanying tables**.

*Deities and Demigods (p 35, emphasis mine)*

The table *Abilities by Altered Size* (p 34) only lists Str, Atk and AC. Consequently Dex, Con, Natural Armor stay the same.